# Linear Algebra Consider

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

`I'm having some trouble on this one: consider the set V of all polynomials of degree 2 or less, and let $$\langle u, v \rangle = \int_0^1 \! p(x) \!q(x) \, \mathrm{d} x$$

Find a matrix A such that $$\langle u, v \rangle = u^\top Av$$ and find an orthonormal basis of V with respect to this inner product.

Comment: $u$ is a polynomial, so what do you mean by $u^T$?  And $v$ is a polynomial, so how can you multiply a matrix $A$ by a polynomial?

Comment: Also, your formula for $\langle u, v \rangle$ doesn't appear to use $u$ or $v$.

Comment: When I'm referring to $u^{\top}$, I'm referring to writing the polynomial as columns, so that for example $3x^2+6x+2$ would be written as $(3, 6, 2)^{\top}$. 

$\langle u, v \rangle$ refers to the inner product of a polynomial of degree 2 or less represented by u and another polynomial represented by v. In the integral, they are written as $p(x)$ for u and $q(x)$ for v.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{e_0,e_1,e_2\}$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb R^3$.  Note that $A$ must satisfy
\begin{align*}
\langle x^i, x^j \rangle &= e_i^T A e_j \\
&= A_{ij}
\end{align*}
for $0 \leq i,j \leq 2$.
This tells us how to compute the entries of $A$.

You can use the Gram-Schmidt process to find an orthonormal basis of $V$ with respect to this inner product.